# Android OpenCV: how to properly call Looper.prepare()

Tags: android, multithreading, opencv

I am working on an app which processes the frames captured by a camera and outputs a `String` with the processing result.

Up until now I can process the frames I need by calling `onClick()`, but now I want to process the frames automatically. The process is not long, maybe I need to use a `Service` (I need advice on this also), but apparently it takes long enough for the device to complain and give `Looper` related errors, like:

`Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`

or, if I have called it, `only one Looper can be created on each thread`

What is the best way of handling this?

**EDIT**
I will attach some code (the relevant parts only)

I am calling OpenCV libraries as:

```
private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
        case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
        {
            Log.i("TAG", "OpenCV loaded successfully");
            mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
            System.loadLibrary("qrwebcam");
            run();
        } break;
        default:
        {
            super.onManagerConnected(status);
        } break;
        }
    }
};
```

Inside the `run()` method I call `onClick()` to perform some image processing operations (I created a function `process(Mat frame)`), which result in a `String` which is shown using a `Toast`.

Shall I convert my `process(Mat frame)` to a `Service` or `Asynctask`?

Comment: If you are doing some background processing and then you want to display something on screen, I believe ASyncTask is the best solution here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please attach related code first.

You are trying to run some code from worker thread and you should do this from main thread (e.g. Activity, AsyncTask, Service).